# Paypal webhook resource is null

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

I have enabled the INVOICING.INVOICE.PAID webhook in my application under developement. After trying to pay an invoice in the sandbox environment (using the buyer test user) the webhook notification is successfully delivered, however the message does not containt the actual invoice data.

As you can see in the JSON below, the resource.invoice property is null.

How can I get the actual data and find the id of the invoice that has been paid?

The webhook notification I receive:

```
{
"id": "WH-6L999276D66321518-9G54023288302824Y",
"create_time": "2017-01-18T22:58:08Z",
"resource_type": "invoices",
"event_type": "INVOICING.INVOICE.PAID",
"summary": "An invoice has been paid",
"resource": {
    "invoice": null
},
"status": "PENDING",
"transmissions": [
    {
        "webhook_url": "https://6fbe15c2.ngrok.io/scc/webhooks",
        "response_headers": {
            "Content-Length": "34",
            "SERVER_INFO": "",
            "Content-Type": "text/plain",
            "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found": ""
        },
        "transmission_id": "945c0220-ddd1-11e6-bc94-77339302725b",
        "status": "PENDING",
        "timestamp": "2017-01-18T22:58:08Z"
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-6L999276D66321518-9G54023288302824Y",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "GET",
        "encType": "application/json"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-6L999276D66321518-9G54023288302824Y/resend",
        "rel": "resend",
        "method": "POST",
        "encType": "application/json"
    }
],
"event_version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Status looks like pending.

Comment: What this status denotes Sunny? In any case shouldn't the invoice details be presented?

Comment: Are you using the REST API?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/invoicing/gs_Invoicing/?mark=Invoice%20Pending

Comment: Yes. I am using the rest api.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the documentation. However I have no problem creating and sending the invoice. The problem is getting notified when the invoice is paid. I am using [webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks) for getting notified but I cannot find the invoice id in the notification message that is received.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133535/discussion-between-sunny-r-gupta-and-michalis-vichos).